# Is sen2cor available as a Python library or can it only be used through the command line?

Tags: python, raster, sentinel, sen2cor

I am looking to correct older Sentinel 2 data to have BOA reflection and would like it to be part of a Python script (I'm working in Windows), but looking online it seems that you can only run sen2cor through the command line. Is there a way to run it directly in a Python script?

Comment: You can always use `subprocess.call()` in your Python script to execute command line utilities.

Comment: true! that's a good idea